# Fail to convert to internal representation (List<Object>)

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I try to convey list of cars in stored procedure, but I get an error.

I have class:

```
public class Car {
  private final int id;
  private final String mark;

  public ProviderVirtualCondition(
        @JsonProperty("id") int id,
        @JsonProperty("mark") String mark) {

    this.id = id;
    this.mark = mark;
  }
}
```

And procedure:

```
create or replace PACKAGE Cars AS
  TYPE car_array IS TABLE OF CAR%ROWTYPE;

  PROCEDURE updateCars(cars in car_array);
END Cars;

create or replace PACKAGE BODY Cars AS
  PROCEDURE updateCars(cars in car_array) AS
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO  car (id, mark) VALUES (cars(1).id, cars(1).mark);
    END updateCars;
END Cars;
```

I want insert List of Car object in DB. I do this:

```
List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
cars.add(new Car(1, "Honda"));
SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue(
            "cars",
            cars
    );
updateCars().execute(in);
```

In updateCars():

```
String carsTypeName = format("%s.%s.%s", schema, PACKAGE, "car_array");
return new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
            .withCatalogName(PACKAGE)
            .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
            .withProcedureName("updateCars")
            .withSchemaName(schema)
            .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("cars",  Types.ARRAY, carsTypeName));
```

And get:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation: [....Car@60c94c7f]
```

How to resolve it?

I resolve it using code from https://coderanch.com/t/589556/framework/Calling-Stored-Procedure-list-values

Comment: Which version of oracle 11, 12?.   
 If you are using oracle 11g Is not possible to work directly with "plsql level types" (there's one exception for associative arrays).  From oracle 12 You can read rowtype arrays in jdbc directly but you can not create it in java and transfer it to oracle. [oracle 12 plsql types](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/apxref.htm#JJDBC29032)

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz i yet used %TYPE. You mean what i can not use %ROWTYPE? Do you hane any idea, to help me?